# how to create a pop up modal on a click event using jquery or knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to link a modal to a click function using knockout. It is supposed to show some text that controller send it in the model object.

this is my JSP:

```
<td>
    <a data-bind="text: name, attr: {href: url}"></a>
    <div data-bind="visible: hasWarning">
        <div id="alerts-modal">
            <img class='warning-icon' src="<c:url   value='/static/image/icons/icon_warning.png'/>" alt="warning"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

my oject is "alertsJson"

I tried this:

```
$('#alerts-modal').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var alerts = resources.alertsJson;

    invokeModal({
        //some code here to create the modal
    });
});
```

Can anybody say why I can not invoke the modal

Comment: Note: an approved edit of this question (revision 2) has fixed a syntax error that may or may not be the source of the issue.

Comment: No it was not the issue.

Comment: it could be a lot of things... are you using bootstrap modals?

Comment: Does `<div id="alerts-modal">` exist when you try to attach the click action to it? Hint: you should probably be using Knockout's click binding.